# Heroku json file rollback

Tags: node.js, json, heroku, discord.js

I'm hosting a discord js bot on heroku, but I've a problem, when the bot restart, all json files rollback to the github file source :
If on my git file.json contain `{ "something": 5 }` and during the execution of my bot, the bot modify the value `{ "something": 10 }`, when the bot will restart, file.json will return to 5 instead of 10. I don't know how to solve that, if somebody has the answer to this problem, it will help me a lot, thanks you in advance, Gamers-geek !

Answer (score 0):

Just change your host. Heroku will always do that since it loads the github each time. Try to find another way to host your bot ^